# Vertical align an image inside a table to the bottom

Tags: html, css

A typical css alignment problem:

```
<table style="width:100px"> <!-- Not actually necessary; just makes the example text shorter -->
   <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;">
         <div style="height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#abc; position:relative;">           
            test of really long content that causes the height of the cell to increase dynamically
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
           <div>text</div>
          <div ></div>
           <img style="vertical-align: bottom;" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/1118727_100000298033362_1412277170_q.jpg"/>
      </td>      
   </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R5TAY/

How would I make the image always appear on the bottom of the table, and the text to stay in the middle?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen to the text in that cell that comes before the image? Should it also appear at the bottom, stuck to the top of the image?

Comment: It should preferably stay in the middle where the whole thing is now. Sorry I was not making myself clear. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, you could use positioning to achieve what you want:

```
td {
    position:relative;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R5TAY/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `vertical-align` css property:

```
#your_td {
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R5TAY/4/)**

Answer (score -3):

Set valign to bottom

```
<td valign="bottom">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: should be made by css instead of an attribute that is deprecated or not even supported anymore in html5